# How to Upload and Download data from OneDrive in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, rest-assured, onedrive

I want to `Upload` and `Download` the data from `One Drive` , How can I achieve this issue , Can anybody help me from in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OneDrive Web API](https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm) and [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)